Can I use my ESTA with just a few weeks left on it?
I'm planning a trip to the US from November 20th till the 28th. My ESTA is not supposed to expire until December 11th. Do I need to apply for a new one?

Yes you can still use it, it's valid until it expires.

@Midavalo To be precise, it's valid for entry until the date it expires, it does not limit how long you can stay in the US afterwards.

If it make you feel better, just apply for a new one.

Your existing ESTA is fine, and you do not need a new ESTA for this trip.
Your ESTA expiration date, December 11, is the last date you can use it to seek entry to the US. So you can even enter the US on December 11, be admitted for 90 days as a Visa Waiver Program visitor, and stay until the beginning of March.

But don't plan to use it on the actual last day, because a flight delay could push you into the next day and make a big mess.  But the three weeks remaining that OP asks about should be just fine.
